# jdk8 executable not launching on windows 10 x64 no errors

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, java, jdk

I have downloaded the jdk8 installer executable for windows x64 from 
The following link (oracle):
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

The file that was downloaded is jdk-8u112-windows-x64.exe
I have administrator permissions. When i try to launch the executable (both with and without using 'run as administrator'), the installation does not occur, with no error indication whatsoever.

When checking my task manager, a proccess titled "java platform SE binary" appears, however nothing else seemingly happens, and of course- the sdk is not installed.

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried restarting? You can also try uninstalling the previous version first.

Comment: Of course, several restart attempts. Also, there is no previous version installed in this case.

Comment: Have you done a checksum on the file to make sure it is not corrupted? The checksum links are on the page you linked to in your question (near the top).